# Modifying queries can only use void or int/Integer as return type

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Modifying queries can only use void or int/Integer as return type when i am trying to do an update on my table.

```
1. thymeleaf

 <div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
 <form  action=""th:action="@{/searchreader(reader_id=${givebook?.getReader()?.getI dNumber()}, book_id=${givebook?.getId()})}"  th:object="${givebook}" class="form-container">

            <label for="book_id"><b>Book ID</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="id" th:value="${reader?.idNumber}" placeholder="Reader ID" hidden/>
            <input type="text"  th:value="${givebook?.getId()}" placeholder="Enter Book ID" name="book_id" required>

            <button type="submit" class="btn">OK</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
        </form>
    </div>

2.Controller

 @GetMapping({"/searchreader","/searchreader{id}","/searchreader{id}/{book_id}"})
    public String searchReaderById(@RequestParam("id") Optional<Long> id, @RequestParam("book_id") Optional<Long> book_id, Model model){

        if(id.isPresent()&&book_id.isPresent()){
            model.addAttribute("givebook",bookRepository.updateBookSetReaderId(id.get(),book_id.get()));
            return "reader/searchreader";
        }
        else
        if(id.isPresent()) {
            Reader reader = readerService.findReaderByIdNumber(id.get());
            model.addAttribute("reader", reader);
            model.addAttribute("messages",readerService.getMessages());

            return "reader/searchreader";
        } else
        {
            return "reader/searchreader";}
        }

3.Repository

    @Transactional
    @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true, flushAutomatically = true)
    @Query(value = "update Book set reader_id=(select r.id from reader r where r.id_Number=:reader_id) where id=:book_id",nativeQuery = true)
    Book updateBookSetReaderId(Long reader_id,Long book_id);
```

While the updated statement return the modified rows, method in repository shoud return void or integer, but when i modify return type void or integer then my controller doesn't work and my thymeleaf template doesn't work too while i use there methods from class Book.

Please any idea.
Thanks.

Comment: Change also the controller code accordingly

Answer (score 1):

In the Repository

```
@Transactional
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true, flushAutomatically = true)
@Query(value = "update Book set reader_id=(select r.id from reader r where r.id_Number=:reader_id) where id=:book_id",nativeQuery = true)
Integer updateBookSetReaderId(Long reader_id,Long book_id);

Book findBookByBookId(Long bookId);
```

In the Controller

```
    if(id.isPresent()&&book_id.isPresent()){
        Book getBook = null;
        Integer updatedRow = bookRepository.updateBookSetReaderId(id.get(),book_id.get());
        if(updatedRow > 0){
        getBook = bookRepository.findBookByBookId(book_id.get());
        }
        model.addAttribute("givebook",getBook);
        return "reader/searchreader";
    }
```